# Android Studio не создает signed apk после обновления до 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio

Обновила `Android Studio` до 2.3, после этого `Android Studio` перестала создавать `signed apk`, пишет, что `apk generated successfully`, но создается только `app-release.apk` и `app-debug.apk`. Я прочитала так же [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765341/android-studio-doesnt-generate-signed-apk-after-update-to-2-3) , в котором говорится, что после апдейта нужно ставить галочки возле двух `Signature version`, но это не решило мою проблему. Как решить такую проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И так, я поставила обе галочки в `Signature version`, сгенирировался файл `app-release.apk`, после этого я сделала `zipalign` этого `apk` и `Google play` принял этот файл.